# How to write like clause using LINQ in silverlight

Tags: linq, silverlight-5.0, sql-like

In my project I want to perform search operation on a Unit list. I have `ObservableCollection<Unit> UnitList` which contains data fetched from SQL Server 2008 using WCF services. I am able to do search using SQL Like in SQL Server but for that I have to call service yet another time which hampers performance.

To solve this I am now trying to use LINQ to filter data according to search parameters on already fetched ObservableCollection. I have write following query:

```
 var result = from u in UnitList
                         where u.UnitNo.Contains(this.UnitNo)
                         && u.ParcelName.Contains(this.ParcelName)
                         && u.TransformationType.Contains(this.TransformationType)
                         && u.TenantName.Contains(this.TenantName)
                         && u.UnitType.Contains(this.UnitType)
                         && u.ClientContact.Contains(this.ClientContact)
                         select u;
```

But it returns value only if all parameters are matched.In SQL Server I used like '%%' for solve
this problem.How to write this in LINQ.

EDIT: I found method `SQLMethods.Like` in one of the solutions on SO but I am unable to use this method in my project. Is there any refrence I need to add for this?

Comment: What kind of data access layer does the service use? (linq to something?) I mean: can't you filter in the service call?

Comment: Of course it will return all parameters, cause you are using && (AND) condition. Maybe you need to us || condition instead of &&?

Method Contains works exactly the same way as LIKE '%%' in SQL server.

Comment: @GertArnold I want to reduce service calls. I can filter data in service call.

Comment: @MichaelSamteladze Tried but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use :

```
List<Units> listUnits = UnitList.Where(d => d.UnitNo == this.UnitNo 
  && d.ParcelName == this.ParcelName 
  && d.TransformationType == this.TransformationType 
  && d.TenantName == this.TenantName 
  && d.UnitType == this.UnitType 
  && d.ClientContact == this.ClientContact ).Tolist();
```

With this, you will put in listUnits all the Units from UnitList who have your parameters.

Fore more information about Linq, check this :

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're sql server installed with case insensitive parameter. 'Contains' is case-sensitive. Just use ToUpper or ToLower on your string.

Comment: I am using LINQ not sql server.

Comment: Yes but  'Contains' in c#  is case-sensitive. Just use ToUpper or ToLower on your string. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) u.ParcelName.ToLower().Contains(this.ParcelName.ToLower())